# Add to each row values from all other rows. sql

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

I got the table

```
ID  
1   
2   
3   
4
```

I want to get table like that.

```
ID  Values
1   234
2   134
3   124
4   123
```

What i am trying to do is to add to each row ID from all other rows.

I tried to use except or not exists method but it doesn't work.

```
union_poly AS (
    SELECT b.id FROM poly b
    EXCEPT (SELECT * FROM poly ct)
    --WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM poly ct WHERE b.id <> ct.id)

  )
```

Comment: With that table data, what is the expected result? (Formatted text here too.)

Comment: is ID a Unique key?

Comment: Beware that you will pretty fast run into some extremely long numbers. E.g. if you have 100 rows, 1.000 rows or 50.000 rows.

Comment: I need it for st_union all geometries except first one. To create big multipolygons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
select id,
       (select string_agg(t2.id::text, '' order by t2.id)
        from t t2
        where t2.id <> t.id
       ) as ids
from t;
```

[Here](http://rextester.com/NIGOQ38085) is a Rextester.  [And](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1e1f4fbf1/17811) a SQL Fiddle (it is rather slow these days).